# Declaring booleans in a domain class without appearing in database

Tags: grails

I have some booleans that are used throughout my grails project (services & controllers, etc) so they are declared in my domain class but I do not want them appearing in the table in the database. Instead of declearing them Boolean I tried Def but this isn't working. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a property of a domain class that does not get stored in the database then use [transients](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html).

Here is a simple example:

```
class Thing {
   String name
   boolean flag
   boolean anotherFlag
   static transients = ['flag', 'anotherFlag']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I picked up from one of the grails videos by Burt Beckwith was in grails domain classes if you define a `getter` or a `setter` without declaring the object itself that itself becomes a transient object by default. So as per above rather than all of the declarations if you had

```
//This will return the same value
boolean getFlag() { 
  return someField && someOtherField 
}
//so you call `object.flag` or `object.getFlag()`
```

This saves from then having to declare a transient value as well giving you the chance to apply some logic on the fly.

In all honesty it appears you are using both the domain class for validation and input. Usually I separate and create a validation class in src to do this part and get domain class to do raw work - keeps it cleaner per say